# How to add background image in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angularjs, background-image

I am trying to insert Background image into my angular application.

**home-component.html**

```html
<body>
    <div style="text-align:center;" class="backgroundimage">
        
    </div>
</body>

<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .backgroundimage {
        background-image: url('/frontend/src/assets/logo');
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
```

I am getting 404 error in browser inspect element network tab.

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404(Not Found)**

How to do this one ?

Comment: `url('assets/logo');`. Think that, when you build an angular app, the "assets" folder are copy in the "root" (the same place you have the index.html) and the .css is also in the "root". NOTE: check your angular.json. in this file find the arrays "assets", only the folders in this array are used to make a copy to the "root/assets" folder

Answer (score 0):

For starters you need to put the CSS code(the one you have enclosed in style tag) in in the css or scss file of that component you are using. The reason why you are getting that 404 error is because the class "backgroundimage" does not exist in your css file. You have it in your html which does not get interpreted as a class